# How to manage ViewModel changes in a CQRS + Event Sourcing Architecture

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, cqrs, event-sourcing

We are currently evaluating CQRS and Event Sourcing architectures.  I am trying to understand what the maintenance implications of using this kind of design are.  Two questions I am struggling to find answers to are this:

1)
What happens if, after an application has been up and running for a while, there is a new requirement to add an additional field to a ViewModel on the ReadModel database? Say, the Customer Zip Code is required on the CustomerList ViewModel, where it was not previously.  So, the extra column can be added to the ViewModel database easily, but how does this get populated?  As far as I can see, the only way is to clear the read database, and replay all the events from scratch to build back up the ReadModel Datbase. But, what if the application has been up and running for months, or years (as we hope it will).  This could be millions of events to replay, just to add data for a zipcode column.

I have the same concern if, for whatever technical reason, the ReadModel Database got out of sync, or we want to add a new ReadModel database. It seems like the older the application is, and the more it is used, the harder and more expensive this is get an up to date readmodel back. Or am I missing a trick somewhere? Something like ReadModel snapshots?

2)
What happens if after all the millions of events have been replayed to build back up the read database, some of the data doesn't line up with what was expected (i.e. it looks wrong). It is thought that perhaps a bug somewhere in the event storing, or denormalizing routines may have caused this (and it seems that if there is one thing you can rely on in coding, it is bugs).  How to go about debugging this!  It seems like an impossible task.  Or maybe, again, I am missing a trick.

I would be interested to hear from anyone who has been running a system like this for a while, how the maintenance and upgrade paths have worked out for you.

Thanks for any time and input.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The beauty of using event sourcing with CQRS is the ability to destroy the read model and rebuild it from scratch, as has been mentioned.  For some reason people have this idea that it's going to take a long time after you get above some arbitrary number of events.  If you are using a relational database for your read models--and you most likely are--it's easy to open up a transaction, read into all of the events through the handlers and then commit the transaction.  It's only when the transaction commits that we actually touch the disk.  Everything else is performed in memory so it can be lightning fast.  In fact, I wouldn't be surprised to see your system crank through a few million events in just a few minutes, if that.

Rebuilding your read models from scratch should display the exact same way as your everyday method of denormalizing the events into the read models.  If not, you've got a bug in your read model denormalization code.  The great thing here is that from your message handler perspective there's no difference between an event being received and denormalized into the read model during regular/production scenarios and for read-model rebuild scenarios.

If you do encounter bugs you can easily debug by streaming/copying the production events to your local workstation, setting breakpoints in your handlers, and then running those events through your read model handling code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your views on event replay time not being an issue (even for millions of events) is reassuring. I enjoy your blog BTW, thanks for sharing!

Comment: You'll definitely want to do some testing because view model population *can* be slow if you do it wrong.  It takes a little bit of effort to make it fast.

Comment: We have been in the practice or rebuilding our read model on every push to production.  We first rebuild the data pushing it to our stage read model and if the rebuild succeeds we will do the rebuild and push it to our production read model.  For us it ensures that the read model reflects all of the modifications to event handlers in each release.

Comment: "The beauty of using event sourcing with CQRS is the ability to destroy the read model and rebuild it from scratch, as has been mentioned". Strange reason for adopting CQRS style, the ability to destroy database...

Comment: Even though you're dropping a database which may contain a projection of the events, you're not losing any data.  Instead, you'd typically only drop a database when the business needs change and no longer require the particular view(s) in question.  Then, you can re-play your events against a new set of handlers to create a different view/projection according to current business needs--all without truly losing data.

Comment: @JonathanOliver in terms of rebuilding, is it recommended that you replicate the events stream from the write-side on the read-side? At the moment I just update my read model from the events raised from the write-side, however, in the case where I need to drop my read DB how do I rebuild? It seems like unnecessary work to have to pull all the events from the domain side back across to the read side again, it seems to me that caching these events in a read-side event stream is the most optimal approach here? Not sure if there are any pitfalls there or if you can think of a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

I am somewhat new to CQRS, so this may not be the most advisable route (but iirc I picked it up from one of the CQRS/DDDD mailing lists).

We create a command and corresponding handler specific to the purpose that is expected to be run once then deprecated.

In the handler we use whatever mechanism is convenient, so in your case of adding a zip code field, we may run a one-off query that pulls the zip codes at that moment from another view model and populates the new column.  We don't worry to much about architectural purity in these scenarios, as it is expected to be a one-time operation ([Rob Conery's Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) has been used with success in these situations).

Comment: Yes, an engineer that put in production a couple of ES/CQRS architecture told me that used to treat data model changes as regular events and try to manage them the best way. It's especially tricky when the read side has to deal with attributes cancelation more than adding, because in that case you have just to update your code (when strongly typed) and provide default values

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet got production-ready app using cqrs with event sourcing, so here is just my experience trying to build one.

1) `Read Model rebuild`. Yep, you basically have to rebuild whole Read Model DB once something in it changes. And if there are lots of events, this may take a long time. So the Read Model rebuilding must be highly optimized (use event batching, etc.). I feel event sourcing fits best in cases when there is high read-write ratio. So for some extremely volatile data, it may be wise not to store it as domain events. But then the question about storage capacity is also not that far away. In any case, you can apply cqrs to just a part of the system, the one where it fits best (e.g., I probably wouldn't store graphical image as part of the event).

2) `Debugging`.
It is highly improbable that there is error in event storing (it should be a framework's concern), and it is always easy to check what events are in the store. As for command to produce expected events, you should have tests here, and these tests will probably be most valuable tests in the system. For denormalizers, you could also have tests, but I wouldn't bother writing tests for trivial denormalizers if their corectness can be seen by naked eye. That being said, I used debugger a few times to find problems in some more complicated denormalizers; it wasn't that much fun trying to determine which event make things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to add in a netting event in your model. This can be run as an arbitrary task after X number of events have been received (say 500)

To rebuild, you push your events onto a stack till you hit the netting event, this gets used as the baseline, from here you pop the events off your stack aggregating their values with your baseline event.